# GpuWatchdog segfault error 6 in libcef.so likely on CPU 15 (core 7, socket 0)

Tags: gnome, crash, radeon, segmentation-fault

Gnome freezes completely and doesn't recover when I alt+tab sometimes, I have this error in the logs:

```
[   59.269235] GpuWatchdog[7736]: segfault at 0 ip 00007fb3a3d92b86 sp 00007fb3989fd370 error 6 in libcef.so[7fb39f8ef000+7770000] likely on CPU 15 (core 7, socket 0)
```

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS with a Radeon rx 5600 xt. Any idea why and how to solve it?

Comment: I've started seeing this recently when switching my monitor on (from an off state with the PC already running). `libcef` is something to do with Chrome/ium. I kill Chrome over SSH but nothing brings the session back to usable and I have to reboot. Are you using Chrome? In my case I'm using an Nvidia card.

Comment: No, I am using Firefox. But it usually happens while playing with Steam open (and steam is chromium too). So I doubt is related to this exactly but it might be. Sadly is not easily reproducible

Comment: Opened a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-6.2/+bug/2045951